# How to use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT in Android Pie

Tags: java, retrofit2, androidx, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

I'm making a profile photo change function using Retrofit in android pie.

So I succeeded in uploading the photos taken with the camera to the server.
But I don't know how to transfer the photos selected from the gallery to my server.
(I'm fine with any kind of code in Java Kotlin.)

*I will upload the video later.*

I searched a lot on Google, but it was hard to get the information I wanted.

Well done in the google doc but i don't know how to do it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

The Google doc shows examples of using bitmap or inputstream or something.

Do I need a bitmap or inputstream to upload photos using Retrofit?

I actually need a valid uri.

```
public void performFileSearch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURES_DIR_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode ==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            showImage(uri);
        }
    }
}


public void Edit_Profile (String Image_Uri) {
    File file = new File(Image_Uri);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("image/*"));

    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", Num+ID+".jpg", requestBody);
}
```

In fact, onActivityResult returns the following type of uri.

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A191474
```

So when I try to send it to my server using that uri I get a FileNotFoundException error.

Comment: If you can get and display the image , before sending to the server, try converting it into a base64 encoded and transfer the string you will get.

Comment: Use the `InputStreamRequestBody` found in the second code snippet of [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196) to create a `RequestBody` for a `Uri`.

Comment: Can you help me will listing all files in android-Q from Download directory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593112/do-we-need-permission-to-get-all-files-that-is-self-created-by-the-app-after-the

Answer (score 7):

This is a privacy restriction introduced in Android-Q. Direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated when an app targets API 29 and the path returned from [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Use the app-specific directory to write & read files.

*By default, apps targeting Android 10 and higher are given [scoped access into external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped), or scoped storage. Such apps can see the following types of files within an external storage device without needing to request any storage-related user permissions:*

Files in the app-specific directory, accessed using getExternalFilesDir().
Photos, videos, and audio clips that the app created from the media store.

- Files in the app-specific directory, accessed using [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).
- Photos, videos, and audio clips that the app created from the [media store](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/media).

Go through the documentation [Open files using storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#search)

> Coming to the context, One thing that you can do is that as
>   CommonsWare suggested use `InputStreamRequestBody`. Otherwise, copy
>   the selected file to your app sandbox folder IE, app-specific
>   directory, then access the file from there without any permission.
>   Just see the below implementation that works in Android-Q and later.

**Perform file search**

```
private void performFileSearch(String messageTitle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("application/*");
        String[] mimeTypes = new String[]{"application/x-binary,application/octet-stream"};
        if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, messageTitle), OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            Log.d("Unable to resolve Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT {}");
        }
    }
```

**onActivityResult returned**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent resultData) {
        // The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE.
        // If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the response to some other intent,
        // and the below code shouldn't run at all.
        if (requestCode == OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
                // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
                // provided to this method as a parameter.  Pull that uri using "resultData.getData()"
                if (resultData != null && resultData.getData() != null) {
                    new CopyFileToAppDirTask().execute(resultData.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d("File uri not found {}");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("User cancelled file browsing {}");
            }
        }
    }
```

**File writing to app specific path**

```
public static final String FILE_BROWSER_CACHE_DIR = "CertCache";

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class CopyFileToAppDirTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private CopyFileToAppDirTask() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
        try {
            return writeFileContent(uris[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Failed to copy file {}" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String cachedFilePath) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
          if (cachedFilePath != null) {
                Log.d("Cached file path {}" + cachedFilePath);
            } else {
               Log.d("Writing failed {}");
         }

    }
}

private String writeFileContent(final Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream selectedFileInputStream =
            getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    if (selectedFileInputStream != null) {
        final File certCacheDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_BROWSER_CACHE_DIR);
        boolean isCertCacheDirExists = certCacheDir.exists();
        if (!isCertCacheDirExists) {
            isCertCacheDirExists = certCacheDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (isCertCacheDirExists) {
            String filePath = certCacheDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getFileDisplayName(uri);
            OutputStream selectedFileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = selectedFileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                selectedFileOutPutStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            selectedFileOutPutStream.flush();
            selectedFileOutPutStream.close();
            return filePath;
        }
        selectedFileInputStream.close();
    }
    return null;
}

  // Returns file display name.
    @Nullable
    private String getFileDisplayName(final Uri uri) {
        String displayName = null;
        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(uri, null, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                displayName = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i("Display Name {}" + displayName);

            }
        }

        return displayName;
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me will listing all files in android-Q from Download directory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593112/do-we-need-permission-to-get-all-files-that-is-self-created-by-the-app-after-the

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? That with Android Q you need 50+ lines of code to read a file from, say, the common downloads folder?

Comment: In an answer pertaining to Android-Q, why are you a class that's deprecated in Oreo (ProgressDialog)? Doesn't inspire confidence in the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perhaps more general solution that allows the AsyncTask class to be separate, rather than embedded in an activity. It also returns a response to your activity when the task is complete, and uses a ProgressBar rather than the deprecated ProgressDialog.

The async task:

```
public class FileLoader extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, String>
{
    private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public interface AsyncResponse {
    void fileLoadFinish(String result);
    }
    FileLoader(Context ctx , AsyncResponse delegate) {
        contextRef = new WeakReference<>(ctx);
        this.delegate =  delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
        Context context = contextRef.get();
         ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = uris[0];
        try {
            String mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri);
            Cursor returnCursor =
                contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            returnCursor.moveToFirst();
            String fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
            InputStream inputStream =  contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

            File downloadDir = 
              context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File f = new File(downloadDir +  "/" + fileName);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream,out);
            returnCursor.close();
            return  f.getPath();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        delegate.fileLoadFinish(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

and in your activity:

```
private static final int DIR_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 13;
public void performFileSearch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = new String[]{"application/gpx+xml","application/vnd.google-earth.kmz"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose KMZ or GPX file"), DIR_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        Log.d("****File","Unable to resolve Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT");
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent resultData)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    if (requestCode == DIR_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (resultData != null)
        {
            Uri uri = resultData.getData();

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new FileLoader(this,
                new FileLoader.AsyncResponse(){
                    @Override
                    public void fileLoadFinish(String result){
                        processFile(new File(result));
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }).execute(uri);
         }
    }
}
```

My example attempts to find either .kmz files or .gpx files. The progress bar (if you need one, for long-running file operations) needs to be initialised (and hidden) in OnCreate():

```
mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

My 'processFile()' method takes a while manipulating a map in the main activity so I have waited until it's done before hiding the ProgressBar.

I remain surprised that it takes such a lot of code to perform such a simple operation: to copy a file and make it available for use!